# Installed a new two separate single-pole switches, cannot turn on one of the lights

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I replaced my two separate single-pole switches and now I cannot turn on one of the lights. The left switch is able to turn off and on the lights normally but the right one doesn't do anything to the lights.

Thank you for your help

**EDIT: Before pictures**
[image]

**After pictures**
[image]

**Update: So looks like the light is stuck on and the right switch doesn't do anything is unable to turn on or off.**

[image]

Comment: 1 - Very confused about the terminology. I *think* that you have two separate single-pole switches - i.e., two individual switches that each control one or more lights. But "dual pole" sounds like "3-way switch", which is not what you installed. Please clarify. 2 - Highly recommend using the side screws instead of the back stabs, particularly as you may need to remove/replace wires to get things working. 3- Do you have any "before" pictures?

Comment: Do either of your switches have an unused black screw on the non-visible side of them?   Also, why was the original one a 2-pole switch?  Do you mean a 3-way??? Or a tandem switch (2 switches 1 yoke)?

Comment: Yes I meant two separate single pole switches that control two lights. I just added the before pictures.

Comment: It's odd that the diagram on the box shows wiring for a switch loop when those aren't code approved these days.

Comment: My first guess would be that you have a loose connection in one of the orange wire nuts.

Comment: So the bedroom lights is on but I cannot turn it off at all with the right switch. The left switch is working fine and can turn off/on the other light in the closet. I uploaded a new picture, much appreciated if someone can check my wiring. Thanks!